# Swift - Find highest value in custom class array with multiple variables

Tags: arrays, swift

I'd like to find the highest value in my array. I found the method .max() in Apples documentation.

```
let heights = [67.5, 65.7, 64.3, 61.1, 58.5, 60.3, 64.9]
let greatestHeight = heights.max()
print(greatestHeight)
// Prints "Optional(67.5)"
```

My array has custom datatype. The datatype contains two variables from type integer. How can I find the highest value from one of the variables?

This is my class.

```
class Example: Codable {

// Variables
var value1: Int
var value2: Int

// Init
init(_value1: Int, _value2: Int) {
    value1 = _value1
    value2 = _value2
}
```

}

Comment: conform to protocol `Comparable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you clarified in a comment:

> I want to find out the highest value of value1 of all objects in that array

That can be achieved by mapping each object to its `value1` and then determining
the maximum:

```
let maxValue1 = examples.map { $0.value1 }.max()
```

If the given array is really huge then it can be advantageous to
use the “lazy variant” to avoid the creation of an intermediate array:

```
let maxValue1 = examples.lazy.map { $0.value1 }.max()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by conforming to the `Comparable` protocol and implement `func <` (in this case I compare the sum of the 2 values)

```
struct Example: Codable, Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Example, rhs: Example) -> Bool {
        return lhs.sum < rhs.sum
    }

    // Variables
    var value1: Int
    var value2: Int

    // Init
    init(_value1: Int, _value2: Int) {
        value1 = _value1
        value2 = _value2
    }

    var sum: Int {
        return value1 + value2
    }
}


let array = [Example(_value1: 1, _value2: 4), Example(_value1: 2, _value2: 3)]

print(array.max())

//Example(_value1: 1, _value2: 4)
```

Comment: isn't he trying to only get the highest value in that class instance ?

Comment: altho, the answer is good, and helpful would you mind to keep it that way >:D i'll upvote it good info provided

Comment: i am not the OP we just share the same name.

Comment: I noticed - very confusing!! 

Answer (score 2):

Well, a `Class` instance  is not an `Array` so you can't access the `Array` `functions`  however you can use a custom `func` inside  to get the bigger value.

something like this is an option.

```
class Example: Codable {

// Variables
var value1: Int
var value2: Int

// Init
init(_value1: Int, _value2: Int) {
    value1 = _value1
    value2 = _value2
}
        func max() -> Int {
        if value1 > value2 {
            return value1
        }
        return value2
    }
}

 // USAGE
var example = Example(_value1: 10, _value2: 20)

example.max()
```

UPDATE: as the OP pointed out he need to compare the first value only. 
edit on @Ashley answer, this would solve it

as `.max()` will return the `object` the contains the highest `Value1`.

```
struct Example: Codable, Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Example, rhs: Example) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value1 < rhs.value1
    }

    // Variables
    var value1: Int
    var value2: Int

    // Init
    init(_ value1: Int, _ value2: Int) {
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
    }
}


let array2 = [Example(1, 4), Example(2,3)]

print(array2.max()?.value1)
```

Comment: My english isn't really good, sorry. I don't want to find out the higher value in one object. I want to find out the highest value of value1 of all objects in that array.

Comment: @Tobi check my Updated Answer